# Does someone have a method to import HPLC chromatogram raw data?

Tags: r, import

I am interested in exploring HPLC raw data in R.

I would like to explore the full data from all channels (3d, and four 2d channels).

I am using Empower Pro to produce the data.

Export formats include

- ASCII .arw
- AIA .cdf
- OpenLynx .rpt

Example files are available at:

[.arw file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2499934/raw27796.arw)

[.cdf file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2499934/raw27795.cdf)

I am at this point unable to get information on the structure of the file type.

Using tools such as read.csv, it appears that either the files do not contain the 3d chromatogram data or this data can not be imported in this way.

Thanks to @Ben Bolker, I was able to open a connection to the .cdf file using the "ncdf" package, but it too appears mostly empty (problem with file or import?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy to read these data:

```
X <- read.csv(url("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2499934/raw27796.arw"),skip=2,
              header=FALSE)
plot(X$V1,X$V2,type="l")
```

Beyond this, I know nothing about HPLC analysis but I suggest:

```
library("sos")  ## you may have to install the package first
findFn("HPLC")
```

Hope that's helpful.  It does answer the narrowly posed question ("how do I import these data"); maybe someone with more subject-area knowledge can say what you would do thereafter.

**PS** From some Googling, it looks like "AIA CDF" is a form of NetCDF file; R does have tools to handle that data format as well (again, `findFn("NetCDF")`): see also http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html

Comment: Thank you once more for providing an import method!  However, either all the data is not contained in the .arw (as it should) or the data can not be fully recovered from the .arw file simply using read or scan.  findFn("HPLC") did not appear to yield anything on my system (led to a temp file not found).  However, your tip about the NetCDF did pan out.  I found an outdated package "ncdf", which could at least open the file, though it did not manage to extract values.  I am starting to think that the export of raw data from  Empower Pro is partial.

Comment: Well, it's pretty easy to see what's in the .arw file, since it's just ASCII text -- double-clicking on your link opens it in the browser for me, and it's clear that the information there is just a single list of x-y values. My guess about `findFn` is that you're using Rstudio -- `findFn` doesn't work from within Rstudio ... Sadly, this is looking more like an Empower Pro question than an R question.

Comment: I was scared this would be an Empower Pro question!  And you guessed right, I am using RStudio.  Is the etiquette for me to delete this question until I resolve the Empower Pro problem?